# How to pass a list as a JUnit5's parameterized test parameter?

Tags: java, kotlin, junit5, parameterized-unit-test

I want to parameterize my JUnit5 tests using three parameters: `string`, `string` and `list<string>`.

No luck so far when using `@CsvSource`, which is the most convenient way of passing params for my use case:

> No implicit conversion to convert object of type java.lang.String to
>   type java.util.List

The actual test is:

```
@ParameterizedTest()
@CsvSource(
  "2,1"
 )
fun shouldGetDataBit(first: Int, second: String, third: List<String>) {
    ...
}
```

Any idea if this is possible? I'm using Kotlin here but it should be irrelevant.

Comment: You say "three parameters: `string`, `string` and `list<string>`", but your example has `Int, String, List<String>`.  Were those intended to be consistent with each other?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There is no reason to use a *hack* as suggested by StefanE.

> At this point I'm pretty sure Junit5 Test Parameters does not support anything else than primitive types and CsvSource only one allowing mixing of the types.

Actually, JUnit Jupiter supports parameters of any type. It's just that the `@CsvSource` is limited to a few primitive types and `String`.

Thus instead of using a `@CsvSource`, you should use a `@MethodSource` as follows.

```java
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("generateData")
void shouldGetDataBit(int first, String second, List<String> third) {
    System.out.println(first);
    System.out.println(second);
    System.out.println(third);
}

static Stream<Arguments> generateData() {
    return Stream.of(
        Arguments.of(1, "foo", Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c")),
        Arguments.of(2, "bar", Arrays.asList("x", "y", "z"))
    );
}
```

Comment: FYI: I updated the User Guide for JUnit 5.1 to include such an example. https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/commit/eb6e401fde681d7da649025391691ff5a45ca0f0

Comment: The resulting documentation change is already visible in the latest snapshots: http://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests-sources-MethodSource

Comment: Using MethodSource for this need is overkill. This is a common requirement for so much application. JUnit should provide a simpler way to inject a list of argument without having to deal with MethodSource. Something like @ListSource("value1" , "value2", "value3") would be perfect

Comment: "`@CsvSource` is limited to a few primitive types and `String`" — I don't think that's quite true.  I think it's limited to anything that [`DefaultArgumentConverter`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.9.2/api/org.junit.jupiter.params/org/junit/jupiter/params/converter/DefaultArgumentConverter.html) can handle.  That is primitives and their wrappers, String, `java.time` date/time types, a handful of other common types (`File`, `BigDecimal`, etc.), and anything with a single String factory method or a single String constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Provide the third element as a comma separated string and the split the string into a List inside you test.

At this point I'm pretty sure Junit5 Test Parameters does not support anything else than primitive types and CsvSource only one allowing mixing of the types.

Comment: Well, I'm doing this already - just hoped for something less "hacky"

Comment: I am using only one value providing a JSON string instead for flexibility and no hacks needed. The Test parameter function is still in Beta, hopefully support for objects will come later on..

Comment: FYI: there is no need for a hack. Please see my answer for details.

Comment: "At this point I'm pretty sure Junit5 Test Parameters does not support anything else than primitive types" — I don't think that's quite true.  I think it's limited to anything that [`DefaultArgumentConverter`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.9.2/api/org.junit.jupiter.params/org/junit/jupiter/params/converter/DefaultArgumentConverter.html) can handle.  That is primitives and their wrappers, String, `java.time` date/time types, a handful of other common types (`File`, `BigDecimal`, etc.), and anything with a single String factory method or a single String constructor.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to pass in a delimited list as part of the CSV (for instance, maybe it really does make the code look a lot cleaner), you can use the [explicit conversion](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests-argument-conversion-explicit) functionality of JUnit using a custom [`ArgumentConverter`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.9.2/api/org.junit.jupiter.params/org/junit/jupiter/params/converter/ArgumentConverter.html).

```java
@CsvSource({
        "Two item list,A;B",
        "Single item list,C",
        "Null list,",
        "Empty list,''"
})
@ParameterizedTest
public void testMethod(String listDescription,
                       @ConvertWith(StringToStringListArgumentConverter.class)
                       List<String> list) {
    // ...
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public static class StringToStringListArgumentConverter
        extends TypedArgumentConverter<String, List> {
    protected StringToStringListArgumentConverter() {
        super(String.class, List.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected List convert(String source)
            throws ArgumentConversionException {
        if (source == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (source.isEmpty()) {
            return List.of();
        } else {
            return List.of(source.split(";"));
        }
    }
}
```

### Fully generic list conversion

If you're planning on using the list conversion in multiple places with different element types in each place (e.g. `List<String>`, `List<Integer>`, `List<LocalDate>`), you could create a generic argument converter that delegates to a different argument converter to convert the different element types).

The following is an example that uses the Google Guava [`TypeToken`](https://guava.dev/releases/31.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html) class to determine the list element type, and the built-in internal JUnit [`DefaultArgumentConverter`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.9.2/api/org.junit.jupiter.params/org/junit/jupiter/params/converter/DefaultArgumentConverter.html) to perform the element conversions:

```java
@CsvSource({
        "Two Integer list,1;2",
        "Single Integer list,3",
        "Null list,",
        "Empty list,''"
})
@ParameterizedTest
public void testMethod(String listDescription,
                       @ConvertWith(StringToListArgumentConverter.class)
                       List<Integer> list) {
    // ...
}

public static class StringToListArgumentConverter
        implements ArgumentConverter {
    @Override
    public Object convert(Object source, ParameterContext context)
            throws ArgumentConversionException {
        if (source != null && !(source instanceof String)) {
            throw new ArgumentConversionException("Source must be a string");
        }
        if (!List.class.isAssignableFrom(context.getParameter().getType())) {
            throw new ArgumentConversionException("Target must be a list");
        }
        String sourceString = (String) source;
        if (sourceString == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (sourceString.isEmpty()) {
            return List.of();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("UnstableApiUsage")
        Class<?> elementType =
                TypeToken.of(context.getParameter().getParameterizedType())
                        .resolveType(List.class.getTypeParameters()[0])
                        .getRawType();

        return Arrays.stream(sourceString.split(";"))
                .map(s -> DefaultArgumentConverter.INSTANCE
                        .convert(s, elementType))
                .toList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great I used this approach with converter to pass the whole input objects in form of custom strings into CSV parametrized tests